# Using a timer when the watch goes in sleep mode

Tags: swift, timer, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to use a timer for an exercise app on Apple Watch (timer used for resting time after an exercise) but this timer stops when the watch goes in sleep mode (triggered by a wrist down). This is very unpractical as the user does the wrist down naturally during resting and the timer is stopped.

I am using a basic timer with publish and on receive:

`let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()`

```
.onReceive(timer) { _ in
    if timeRemaining > -1 {
        timeRemaining -= 1
    }
```

but it does not work whenever the user does a wrist down.

Can you please let me know how should I use the timer in order to work even in sleep mode? I see that the Apple Exercise app timer works even in sleep mode. Therefore, that should be doable.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to track the amount of time the user is resting for, you can save the current time in `applicationWillResignActive` in ExtensionDelegate and then in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, you can get the elapsed time using `Date().timeIntervalSince(timeWhenWristDown)`.

If your aim is to remind the user that their rest time is over, you can create a local notification in `applicationWillResignActive` with the trigger time being the current time + the amount of time you want to give the user to rest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I think the notification will be the best approch.

For the count down, I used this code and it solves the problem perfectly. Thanks

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: WKExtension.applicationWillResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
    print("Moving to the background")
    notificationDate = Date()
}
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: WKExtension.applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
    print("Moving to the foreground")
    let deltaTime: Int = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(notificationDate))
    timeRemaining -= deltaTime
    percent += Double(deltaTime) / 1.2
}
```

For the notification, I used a simple test notification with a 5 second timer. It works perfectly when I quit the app before the 5 sec countdown, but not when I stay in the app with a wrist down (to put the watch in sleep mode)

```
func scheduleNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Rest time is over"
    content.subtitle = "Be ready for the next set"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    // show this notification five seconds from now
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

    // choose a random identifier
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // add our notification request
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
```

Should I use something different in order to make this notification work even if I stay in the app in sleep mode?

I am not too familiar with the UserNotifications framework :(

Thank you in advance for your feedback